# Spring Class.getAnnotationsByType does not work correctly when I introduce AOP

Tags: spring, aop

I have a Bean in Spring with a custom Annotation.

```
@Target(ElementType.TYPE)
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface CliCommand {
    Slice slice();
}
```

During runtime (startup) I want to load all classes that have this annotation.

During this process I call.

```
CliCommand[] cliAnnotations = myclass.getAnnotationsByType(CliCommand.class);
```

Before I introduced AOP it worked fine.

However now this returns NULL.

My AOP looks like this.

```
@Pointcut("within(com.companyx.cli..*)")
public void cliLayer() {
}

@Before("cliLayer()")
public void injectCLI(JoinPoint jp){
    MDC.put(ConnectApplicationContext.LOG_LAYER_NAME, Layer.CLI);
}
```

I am not sure why this is happening. Has anyone seen this before. Is it something to do with the cgLib?

Comment: I have noticed something.

Answer (score 0):

Cglib generates child of your class when creating proxy. So if 'myclass' in your example was obtained via `someCglibObject.getClass()` you will get cglib subclass, not yours.

In this case to make annotations declared on parent class to be available via `childClass.getAnnotationsByType` you should annotate your custom annotation with `@Inherited`

Comment: Much appreciated. I moved to using the class constructs to examine the class and it all worked out. I did this by calling   `Class cliPrototypeClass = applicationContext.getType(beanName); ` Instead of `Map<String, CliCommand> beansOfType = applicationContext.getBeansOfType(CliCommand.class);`  Agree though your answer is spot on. Thanks.